# Creating a backup script involving screens and java?

Tags: ssh, backup, shell, cron, gnu-screen

Hi guys I use centOS 64bit 5.7 and I need to create a backup script

What I want it to do:

- screen -r example
- command into java
- pause for x amount of seconds
- exit screen
- zip/rar a folder which and put a timestamp on the name (with date) and move it to a different location
- pause for duration of the zipping? If not a predetermined time.
- screen -S example java -Xmx3g -Xincgc -jar server.jar nogui

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I presume the screen requirement is so that you can initiate the backup process and then log out.  If this is the case, disowning it will achieve the same thing.

Write a script that does all of the other stuff(zipping, filename with date, pausing, moving, etc.) and then start it in the background like so:

```
./my-backup-script.sh &
```

Then run:

```
disown
```

Then you can disconnect (or get disconnected by network issues) and the script will continue to run.  It's worth making sure you redirect STDOUT and STDERR to files because once you disown the job, these two streams will be deleted.

Comment: so that "disown" gets put into the java command inside the screen? 

This makes me go back into ssh?

Comment: No, `disown` should be used **instead** of `screen` and you run it manually after you have started the backup script.  The only purpose of it is so that you can log out while the backup is running.  Please let us know if my guess about why you wanted `screen` was wrong.

Comment: The thing is I plan to set this up as an automatic thing to happen via cronjob every hour. I can't do anything manually. The screen is used because it loads a program in java which has a console.

Comment: The disown command won't be necessary if you start the script from a cron job.  Cron jobs are designed to be run when you are not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Did it myself. Thanks anyway guys.

```
STAMP=`date +%d-%m-%Y_%H%M%S`

screen -x example -X stuff "`printf "command"`"
pause 10;
screen -x example -X stuff `printf "commandr"`
pause 10;
kill `pidof example`
tar -cvzf /directory/of/folder/I/want/backups/to/go/$STAMP-backup.tar.gz /directory/of/folder/I/want/backed/up/
screen -S example java -Xmx3g -Xincgc -jar server.jar nogui
screen -x example -X stuff `printf "save-on\r"`
screen -x example -X stuff `printf "save-all\r"
```